# Check if userinput value exists in localStorage JSON Object already?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, user-input, key-value

I am making a login system for my website. Managed to make the registration and login work using localStorage (so it stores destails there in an array for each account)

However, I want it to display an error if they enter their username wrongly or one that does not exist [so one which is not in the localStorage].

I managed to do this for the password, once the username entered is correct, here is the code for the password check:

```
else if (passwordLogin !== parse.password) {
    message.innerHTML = "Incorrect account information!";
    return;
}
```

^ where *passwordLogin* is what they input in the password field and *parse* is a function that parse localstorage for their username so: *JSON.parse(localStorage[usernameLogin]* - **usernameLogin** is what they input in the username field

NOW I am trying to do the same for username. This is my best code so far:

```
if (localStorage[usernameLogin] === undefined) {
    message.innerHTML = "No such ninja username exists!"; 
}
```

So *usernameLogin* is what they input in the username field. 
I am checking for their input in the localStorage and check if it is *undefined*. In the localStorage the **key** of each account is it's username and **value** is an array with all details like: {"username":"Jordan","password":"asd"}[ where the key of this is just plain Jordan ]

As you notice this username and pass checks are in an if and else if loop. The if (username check) does not do anything but the code for password check works in the else if (only works if the username entered exists and the password does not match )

Maybe the

```
=== undefined
```

is incorrect. Any thoughts are appreciated :)

Comment: You do understand that saving the confidential details such as username and password in localStorage is a big security flaw?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem(usernameLogin)` will get your username, if it does not exist it returns `null`. So your check would be `if (!localStorage.getItem(usernameLogin))`

Comment: I concur with @RahulB, are you sure this is the way u want to design your website a major security flaw, and if the user clears the browsing history including the localStorage your users will no longer be stored and will have to register again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking `undefined` and `empty condtions` can be enough.

```
localStorage.hasOwnProperty('usernameLogin') &&
typeof localStorage.usernameLogin !== 'undefined' &&
localStorage.usernameLogin !== ''
```

You can add conditions with checking the values in it after parsing the value.

```
typeof JSON.parse(localStorage.usernameLogin) === 'object' &&
typeof JSON.parse(localStorage.usernameLogin).password === 'string'
JSON.parse(localStorage.usernameLogin).password === 'yourpassword'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
if (!localStorage.getItem(usernameLogin)) {
    message.innerHTML = "No such ninja username exists!";    
}
```

or

```
if (localStorage[usernameLogin] === undefined) {
    message.innerHTML = "No such ninja username exists!";    
}
```

be sure that the `usernameLogin` variable holds a string.